# Having trouble with Rspec. Getting routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm working on a group project building a chess application & trying to understand why I am getting a routing error when running this test.
I am trying to test the update action in my pieces controller, to make sure that it redirects once a piece is moved.  Bare in mind I am new to testing and am guessing that there is a problem with how I've written this one. Really stuck and could use an explanation of what I am missing.

controller:

```
class PiecesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :update]

  def show
    #show the board again
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @pieces = @game.pieces
  end

  def update
    @piece = Piece.find(params[:id])
    @game = @piece.game

    if @piece.update_attributes(piece_params)
      redirect_to game_path(@game)
    end 
  end

  private

  def piece_params
    params.require(:piece).permit(:x_position, :y_position)
  end
end
```

spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PiecesController, type: :controller do
  describe 'update action' do
    it 'should redirect to game path when piece is moved' do
      user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      game = FactoryGirl.create(:game, white_user_id: user1.id )
      piece = FactoryGirl.create(:piece, game: game, user_id: user1.id, x_position: 0, y_position: 0)

      put :update, params: {x_position: 1, y_position: 1}

      expect(response).to redirect_to game_path(game)
    end
  end
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#index'
  resources :games do
    member do
      patch :join
    end
    resources :pieces, only: [:show, :update]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `id` on `put :update, params: {x_position: 1, y_position: 1}`?

You probably want something like:

```
put :update, id: piece.id, game_id: game.id, piece: {x_position: 1, y_position: 1}
```

Comment: That makes sense, however I'm still getting a no method error failure: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass.  Trying to figure out what isn't being defined properly.

Comment: Oops - it should `piece` and not `@piece`. I've updated the example

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the original failure and now it is assigning a piece id.  BUT now I'm getting a different failure: URLGenerationError No route matches...

Comment: It looks like you did not [authenticate](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)) your user in your spec, so the redirect would be to where unauthenticated users are redirected

Comment: @JanKlimo I'm not sure if that is the issue though.  The error I get is: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"pieces", :id=>13377, :piece=>{:x_position=>1, :y_position=>1}}   I get the same error even when I remove the need for authentication.

Comment: @BrandonElder: try adding `game_id: game.id` to the `put`. It's a nested route, and needs to know the game ID too.

Comment: @gwcodes  Boom...that did it!  Looking at the solution now, it seems pretty obvious.  But I'm new to RoR and even newer to writing tests so.. I really appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: @BrandonElder no problem! Do mark this as the answer if it's helped - I've also updated the answer to include the `game_id`, for posterity